# Grpc Java : Set up SSLContext on Server

Tags: java, ssl, grpc

I want to set-up SSL on my GRPC server.
For that I need certificate chain and a pkcs8 private key.

I have done the following:

## Generate CA key:

openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 4096

## Generate CA certificate:

openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt

## Generate server key:

openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 4096

## Generate server signing request:

openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr

## Self-sign server certificate:

openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out server.crt

## Remove passphrase from the server key:

openssl rsa -in server.key -out server.key

## Conver to pkcs8

openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in server.key -out pkcs8_key.pem

---

Now that I have my **server.cert** and **pkcs8_key.pem** files, I've created the server as such:

```
InputStream certChain = MyServer.class.getResourceAsStream("/server.crt");
        InputStream privateKey = MyServer.class.getResourceAsStream("/pkcs8_key.pem");
        SslContext sslContext = GrpcSslContexts.forServer(certChain, privateKey, "password").build();


        Server server = NettyServerBuilder.forPort(8080)
                            .sslContext(sslContext)
                            .addService(new ChatService())
                            .addService(new HelloWorldService())
                            .useTransportSecurity(certChain, privateKey)
                            .build();
```

The classpath is configured properly.

The error stack I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input stream does not contain valid private key.
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.keyManager(SslContextBuilder.java:296)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.forServer(SslContextBuilder.java:104)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forServer(GrpcSslContexts.java:162)
    at server.MyServer.main(MyServer.java:20)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: overrun, bytes = 2353
    at javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.<init>(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:92)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.generateKeySpec(SslContext.java:978)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.getPrivateKeyFromByteBuffer(SslContext.java:1034)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.toPrivateKey(SslContext.java:1024)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.keyManager(SslContextBuilder.java:294)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is being caused by this line:

```
SslContext sslContext = GrpcSslContexts
    .forServer(certChain, privateKey, "password").build();
```

Since your pkcs8 key has no password, you should not be passing a password and instead use the two-argument method:

```
SslContext sslContext = GrpcSslContexts
    .forServer(certChain, privateKey).build();
```

Note that calling `useTransportSecurity()` will overwrite your call to `sslContext()`, so you shouldn't call both. Calling both would break in the current code because `forServer()` consumes and close the provided `InputStream`s, so you'd be passing closed streams to `useTransportSecurity()`.

Comment: Thanks, I keep getting a new java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/ALPN  ,although i have compile 'io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:2.0.6.Final'   in my gradle file

Comment: Try looking at https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#netty , especially the table at the end